# Show that the risk-neutral probability of a European call option ending in money is N(d2)

Tags: finance

Show that the risk-neutral probability of a European call option ending in money is N(d2).

I was trying to using Risk-Neutral Valuation Formula, but how to show the result is N(d2)?
Thanks

Comment: I think, it is a good idea, if you post the calculations, which you have done, already. More informations about the general subject might also be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.